# UIPageVIewController sendChildViewAppearAnimated crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

[UIPageViewController _sendChildViewWill:appear:animated:] + 290

There's nothing in the stack trace from my app. What's causing this crash?

```
0
libobjc.A.dylib 
objc_msgSend + 5
countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:
1
UIKit   
-[UIPageViewController _sendChildViewWill:appear:animated:] + 290
2
UIKit   
-[UIPageViewController viewDidAppear:] + 68
3
UIKit   
-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 410
4
CoreFoundation  
__53-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke + 52
5
CoreFoundation  
-[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] + 220
6
UIKit   
-[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 724
7
UIKit   
-[UIViewController _endAppearanceTransition:] + 264
8
UIKit   
-[UIWindowController transitionViewDidComplete:fromView:toView:removeFromView:] + 1714
9
UIKit   
__101-[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:]_block_invoke293 + 170
10
UIKit   
-[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 74
11
UIKit   
-[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 288
12
UIKit   
-[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 944
13
UIKit   
-[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 178
14
UIKit   
-[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 70
15
QuartzCore  
CA::Layer::run_animation_callbacks(void*) + 232
16  libdispatch.dylib   
_dispatch_client_callout + 22
23  UIKit   
UIApplicationMain + 1136
24
main.m line 14
```

Comment: are you sure that's where the crash is? You might have X number of threads running and the crash happened somewhere else...

Comment: That's what shows up in the stack trace.. I'll look for other threads